# Sort 2 list linked to each other

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, sorting

I go stuck on a problem and I cannot think of any efficient way to do this. The problem is the following:

I got 2 lists, each with `n` up to `10^3`.

```
v = [v_1, v_2, ..., v_n]
w = [w_1, w_2, ..., w_n]
```

In the following example `n = 3`.

```
v = [60, 100 , 120] 
w = [20, 50, 30]
```

I need to sort both lists based on the decreasing order of the following equation: `v_i/w_i`

So in this case I would get:

```
v_1/w_1 = 3
v_2/w_2 = 2
v_3/w_3 = 4
```

After that I need to sort both lists (depended to each other) by the decreasing order and I would get the following result.

```
v_new = [120, 60, 100]
w_new = [30, 20, 50]
```

I know there is a way with sorted(zip(X,Y), but doing so it would change my list in a tuple and I need it as a list. Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you want to do in-place sorting or would creating a new v and w be fine?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Python's sort functions can take a key, you can use a lambda function to define the key you want to sort over. In this case, i'd suggest sorting the indices and then applying the order to both `v` and `w`. For example:

```
v = [60, 100 , 120] 
w = [20, 50, 30]
order = sorted(range(len(v)), key=lambda i: v[i] / w[i], reverse=True)

v_new = [v[i] for i in order]
w_new = [w[i] for i in order]
```

Comment: I think i forgot to mention that the lists are dependent to each other. So sorting the lists first would mess up the dependency to each other.

Comment: @RobertKodra I think you've misunderstood my answer. `v` and `w` are never sorted. We find the ordering need to sort `v_i / w_i` then create new lists using that ordering.

Comment: Ah I am sorry. Indeed you are right. This works really well. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Sort based on condition using the `key` of `sorted` which then gives a list of tuples and we use `zip` to separate them to two lists:

```
v = [60, 100 , 120] 
w = [20, 50, 30]

v, w = map(list, zip(*sorted(zip(v, w), key=lambda x: - x[0] / x[1])))

print(v)  # [120, 60, 100]
print(w)  # [30, 20, 50]
```

Alternatively, you could use `reverse=True` in the same code like:

```
v = [60, 100 , 120] 
w = [20, 50, 30]

v, w = map(list, zip(*sorted(zip(v, w), key=lambda x: x[0] / x[1], reverse=True)))
```

which also yields what is desired.

Comment: This will work although be aware that `zip` will only work up to the length of the smallest list. - might want to give `itertools.zip_longest` a look as well.

Comment: @JulianCamilleri, OP clearly mentioned both lists are of same length.

Comment: I saw budd, just putting it out there just in case someone else reads this thread.

Comment: it better and more pythonic to use reverse=true instead of negative (-)

Comment: @JulianCamilleri If the lists aren't the same length we shouldn't even try to sort them, since something is drastically wrong. Presumably, the OP can guarantee that the lists have identical length, but if they can't, then that ought to be tested before executing this sorting code.

Comment: The lists are the same length. This method works, but I am wondering how big a list can be for the `zip` function?

Comment: @RobertKodra `zip` returns an iterator, which doesn't use up much RAM. This answer uses a little more RAM than Bi Rico's answer. Austin's produces a temporary sorted list of tuples, Bi Rico's produces a list of integer indices (which you should delete after it's done it's job, although if this code is inside a function that will happen automatically when the function returns). A tuple object containing 2 items is fairly small, it uses a little over double the RAM of a small int object (32 bytes vs 14 bytes). The contents of each tuple will just be pointers to the number objects from `v` & `w`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
v = [60, 100, 120]
w = [20, 50, 30]
vv = pd.Series(v)
ww = pd.Series(w)
new_index = list((vv/ww).sort_values(ascending=False).index.values)
v_new = list(vv.reindex(new_index))
w_new = list(ww.reindex(new_index))
print(v_new)
print(w_new)
```

Output:

> [120, 60, 100]
>
> [30, 20, 50]

Answer (score 0):

The question doesn't mention numpy, but I thought I'd add an answer using numpy because it handles this kind of thing really well. Numpy has an argsort that can be used to apply the ordering of any sort to other arrays, for example:

```
import numpy as np

v = np.array([60, 100 , 120])
w = np.array([20, 50, 30])

order = np.argsort(v / w)[::-1]
v_new = v[order]
w_new = w[order]
```

`argsort` doesn't have a `reverse` argument, but we can always just invert the output using `[::-1]`.